# Что такое APK-файл тестирования? (Firebase test lab)

Tags: java, android, firebase

Я хочу воспользоваться сервисом *Firebase test lab*, выбираю Тестирование на базе Instrumentation, далее чтоб начать тестирование он просит загрузить два файла, первый apk файл приложения, второй apk файл тестирования, помогите разобраться что это за файл тестирования и как его получить?

Comment: Собственно, [вот](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html).